# org.bouncycastle.tls.crypto.TlsCertificate getSubject() and other getters

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have a client that connects to https servers using bouncycastle (ver 1.66)

```
tlsClientProtocol.connect(new DefaultTlsClient(new BcTlsCrypto(new SecureRandom())) {

                @Override
                public TlsAuthentication getAuthentication() throws IOException {
                    return new ServerOnlyTlsAuthentication() {
                        @Override
                        public void notifyServerCertificate(TlsServerCertificate tsc) throws IOException {
                                 // validate srvCert here. here is the problem
                                 TlsCertificate srvCert = tsc.getCertificate().getCertificateAt(0);
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

"srvCert" is an instance of **org.bouncycastle.tls.crypto.TlsCertificate**,
how can I convert it to **org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate** like the old version of BouncyCastle or how can I get "NotBefore", "NotAfter", "Subject"...etc.

PS: I don't care about the issuer chain for now, I just want to print out all the details of the end certificate, also **BcTlsCertificate** is just as useless as the interface **TlsCertificate**.

The BouncyCastle docs are no help, and I'm new to this library, and the examples on the internet are old (before the changes of 1.6 if I'm not wrong)

Edit: Just to be clear, the interface **org.bouncycastle.tls.crypto.TlsCertificate** does not have the methods I need, this class does: **org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate**. But in the last version the method signature was changed to give you the useless class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BouncyCastle has a lot of `getInstance(Object)` methods, which allow you to transform an object into another if it makes sense. To find which transformations are supported the easiest way is to look at the source code.

In your case if `tlsCertificate` contains your instance of `org.bouncycastle.tls.crypto.TlsCertificate`, you can get a `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate` with:

```java
final Certificate certificate = Certificate.getInstance(tlsCertificate.getEncoded());
```

However instead of transforming the `TlsCertificate` into an ASN.1 structure representation I would rather transform it into JCE's `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`:

```java
final X509Certificate x509Certificate;
if (tlsCertificate instanceof JcaTlsCertificate) {
    x509Certificate = ((JcaTlsCertificate) tlsCertificate).getX509Certificate();
} else {
    final CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(tlsCertificate.getEncoded()));
}
```

Comment: This is better than the answer I wanted, thank you. PS: CertificateFactory.getInstance("X[dot]509") is the one I'm used to. I tried it without the dot and it threw an Exception

Comment: You are right: the [standard name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#CertificateFactory) is `X.509`. I tested the answer with BC, so it probably was more tolerant.